# CSS selector for following tags

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have some html code like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>first line </td>
    <td>second line </td>
    <td>third line </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and I just want the "first line" to have red color.
* I couldn't use inline-style  or set class for tags. I just could use an external CSS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) selector. As from Docs:

> The `:first-child` CSS pseudo-class represents the first element among a group of sibling elements.

**Demo:**

```css
table tr td:first-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>first line </td>
    <td>second line </td>
    <td>third line </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **first-of-type**.

```css
table td:first-of-type {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>first line </td>
    <td>second line </td>
    <td>third line </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```